# Export data from Excel to Access using VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, export

I have a table in an Excel file with some data, and I want to export these data to my database on Access (in a concrete table on my database called Water Quality) with a VBA code to avoid to open my Database every time that I want to introduce more data on it.

At the moment I have this code but it's not working...

```
Sub Button14_Click()

' Macro purpose: To add record to Access database using ADO and SQL
' NOTE:  Reference to Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects Libary required

' Exports data from the active worksheet to a table in an Access database

'Dim cnt As New ADODB.Connection
'Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim cnt As DAO.Database
Dim rst As Recordset
Dim dbPath As String
Dim tblName As String
Dim rngColHeads As Range
Dim rngTblRcds As Range
Dim colHead As String
Dim rcdDetail As String
Dim ch As Integer
Dim cl As Integer
Dim notNull As Boolean
Dim sConnect As String

'Set the string to the path of your database as defined on the worksheet
dbPath = "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrador\Mis documentos\MonEAU\modelEAU Database V.2.accdb"
tblName = "Water Quality"
Set rngColHeads = ActiveSheet.Range("tblHeadings")
Set rngTblRcds = ActiveSheet.Range("tblRecords")

'Set the database connection string here
sConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & dbPath & "';"     'For use with *.accdb files
' sConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & dbPath & ";"     'For use with *.mdb files

'Concatenate a string with the names of the column headings
colHead = " ("
For ch = 1 To rngColHeads.Count
    colHead = colHead & rngColHeads.Columns(ch).Value
    Select Case ch
        Case Is = rngColHeads.Count
            colHead = colHead & ")"
        Case Else
            colHead = colHead & ","
    End Select
Next ch

'Open connection to the database
cnt.Open sConnect
'Begin transaction processing
On Error GoTo EndUpdate
cnt.BeginTrans

'Insert records into database from worksheet table
For cl = 1 To rngTblRcds.Rows.Count
    'Assume record is completely Null, and open record string for concatenation
    notNull = False
    rcdDetail = "('"

    'Evaluate field in the record
    For ch = 1 To rngColHeads.Count
        Select Case rngTblRcds.Rows(cl).Columns(ch).Value

                'if empty, append value of null to string
            Case Is = Empty
                Select Case ch
                    Case Is = rngColHeads.Count
                        rcdDetail = Left(rcdDetail, Len(rcdDetail) - 1) & "NULL)"
                    Case Else
                        rcdDetail = Left(rcdDetail, Len(rcdDetail) - 1) & "NULL,'"
                End Select

                'if not empty, set notNull to true, and append value to string
            Case Else
                notNull = True
                Select Case ch
                    Case Is = rngColHeads.Count
                        rcdDetail = rcdDetail & rngTblRcds.Rows(cl).Columns(ch).Value & "')"
                    Case Else
                        rcdDetail = rcdDetail & rngTblRcds.Rows(cl).Columns(ch).Value & "','"
                End Select
        End Select
    Next ch

    'If record consists of only Null values, do not insert it to table, otherwise
    'insert the record
    Select Case notNull
        Case Is = True
            rst.Open "INSERT INTO " & tblName & colHead & " VALUES " & rcdDetail, cnt
        Case Is = False
            'do not insert record
    End Select
Next cl

EndUpdate:
'Check if error was encounted
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    'Error encountered.  Rollback transaction and inform user
    On Error Resume Next
    cnt.RollbackTrans
    MsgBox "There was an error.  Update was not succesful!", vbCritical, "Error!"
Else
    On Error Resume Next
    cnt.CommitTrans
End If

'Close the ADO objects
cnt.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set cnt = Nothing
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

At the moment, the problem is when I debug the code, there appears the compiling error: "Method or data member not found" on the function "cnt.Open sConnect".

If this is possible, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I'm using Office 2010.

Comment: Now the error appears in that line when I debug the code: Invalid use of New Keybord

Answer (score 2):

Your compile error is due to these 2 lines:

```
Dim cnt As DAO.Database
cnt.Open sConnect
```

A `DAO.Database` object does not have an `.Open` method, which explains "*Method or data member not found*".  Too often error messages can be somewhat vague and just not very helpful.  However, in this case, I can't think how the error message could be any more clear.

There is something more which I don't understand.  `sConnect` looks like an ADO connection string.  But `cnt` is a **DAO** (database) object.  You can't mashup the two object models like that in one statement.

You have this just before your active variable declarations:

```
'Dim cnt As New ADODB.Connection
```

Then later in your procedure, you have:

```
'Close the ADO objects
cnt.Close
```

So perhaps you originally intended `cnt` to be an `ADO.Connection` object and didn't adapt the rest of your code after you switched it to a `DAO.Database` object.

I suggest you revise your code to sort out the DAO vs. ADO confusion, then show us the new code if you have any remaining problems.  And please show us only the minimum tested code required to reproduce the problem you're hoping to solve.  TIA for your consideration.

Comment: Thanks! I could solve this problem... There was a confusion between DAO and ADO as you said. Now there are other problems, first I have to check what's failing now.

Answer (score 0):

I only have Access databases that open the excel file (instead of the other way around) but from looking through my code I think you should go straight to this:

```
`Set cnt = OpenDatabase_
       (dbPath, False, True, "Access 8.0;")
```

Found this on http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190195 too.

Does this help?