# Excel VBA Export to Access: ADO Error

Tags: excel, ms-access, ado, vba

I am trying to export a worksheet to Access where it will be paste appended into an existing table. I've referenced [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16949063/export-excel-worksheet-to-access-table-accdb), [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232619/export-data-from-excel-to-access-using-vba), [and this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226004/insert-data-from-excel-into-access-using-vba). I'm getting an error that was not addressed in any of them that I think might be related to VBA libraries but could be something completely different. Here is my code:

```
Sub ExcelToAccessAdo()

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, row As Long
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " & _
        "Data Source=filepath\AccessDB.accdb;" 'this is a different filepath from the real one.

' open a recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open "Table Export", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable

row = 2    ' the start row in the worksheet
Do While Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Table Export").Range("A" & row))

    With rs
        .AddNew    ' create a new record
        .Fields("REPTNO") = Worksheets("Table Export").Range("A" & row).Value
        .Update
    End With
    row = row + 1
Loop

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

The worksheet name and Access table name are the same. Also the `.Fields("REPTNO")` line is straight from the other person's post so I don't know if I'll have to change it or not.

The error is `Run-time error '-2147217900 (80040e14)': Syntax error in FROM clause.`

on the line `rs.Open "Table Export", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable`.

This is a strange error since it seems like an error I'd get when running SQL, but I'm assuming there's some background SQL happening with an `INSERT INTO` clause. Which maybe this is some type of file path issue with Excel? Any help?

Here are my library References:

- Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library
- OLE Automation
- Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library
- Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library
- Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library
- Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects Recordset 6.0 Library

Comment: I'm going to guess that you should probably toss some square brackets around your table name in the `rs.open` statement. I'm not 100% sure on that since I generally only issues sql statements through `rs.open`. Give this a shot: `rs.Open "[Table Export]", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable` and see if it does the trick.

Comment: Yep, that did it! I feel like I should've known to do that...

Do you want to submit an answer and I'll mark it correct, or should I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @JNevill who pointed out I just needed to use square brackets:

`rs.Open "[Table Export]", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable`

Comment: Indeed, any table name with a space/special characters should be enclosed with brackets (and as best practices - never include special characters or spaces in table or field names). Also, table names using [reserved words](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-e33eb3a9-8baa-4335-9f57-da237c63eabe) should use brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Try to stay away from spaces in any object name (Tables, Field_Names, Forms, Reports, etc.).  You can do this, but as you can tell, it's going to cause more time and unnecessary frustration to normalize things.  Also, don't use reserved words in your code.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/286335